# Yellow and blue horizontal stripes across the screen when using my Nvidia GTX 470 with a MSI Twin Frozr III cooling system installed

Tags: video

I think I have a faulty video card. A month ago I bought a secondhand [Nvidia GTX 470](http://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gtx-470) with [MSI Twin Frozr III](http://event.msi.com/vga/twinfrozriii/) cooling. I got it specifically for CUDA rendering with the Adobe suite.

The temperatures for this card ranged from 60 degrees on idle to about 80-90 on load. The video card also made my Intel Core 2 Duo E8500 CPU run a lot hotter than previously. The CPU would go to about 76-78 degrees on full load with the stock cooler from Intel.

I noticed that while rendering with CUDA, the GPU usage did not go up, and the video card would not heat up at all; is this normal? The only times where the video card was stressed was while playing games.

Yesterday I spent the whole day working in After Effects and rendering clips. The CPU, as usual would go to about 78 degrees max, the video card stayed at about 60-70. I’m using an Antec 500W PSU.

In the end I got these blue and yellow horizontal stripes on the screen and I can’t get rid of them; see picture below. I get them before starting Windows, during POST, please see the screenshot Windows reports that the video card has a problem and it's been disabled. Sometimes while booting I also get a BSOD that mentions an Nvidia `.sys` file, I forgot the name.

[image]

I’ve already checked with an older video card and stripes do not appear.

So is there anything I can do about this? Do you think the video card fried? I’ve read some forums that were saying it could be a VRAM issue.

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I couldn't post the image because I wasn't allowed, indeed. I tested the card on another computer and it's indeed faulty. I'll think about "baking"it.

Comment: Was this ever resolved?